# Event firing for each element in selector, need it to fire only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, mouseevent

I have:

```
$('#externalContactsGrid').on('mouseup', '.k-grid-content, tr', function(e) {
    alert('test')
...
})
```

I want it to fire once if the mouse is up on either element, not twice. So I want it to fire on '.k-grid-content' OR 'tr', with 'tr' taking precedence.

tr elements are inside .k-grid-content.

---

I also need the browsers context menu to not show when e.which == 3.

Comment: what is the relationship between both these elements... whether one is an ancestor of another

Comment: tr is a child of table which is a child of '.k-grid-content'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I want it to fire once if the mouse is up*

1. What seems to me is either your alert is comming two times
2. or you want to bind the event for one time only

if case is `1` then probably you want to use `.stopPropagation()` because ***tr elements are inside .k-grid-content**.*

Because events are tend to bubble up the dom meaning whenever an event is bound to any child/grandchild element the event bubbles up to the parents of it. so if parent has any bound event then that would also get fired.

```
$('#externalContactsGrid').on('mouseup', '.k-grid-content, tr', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation(); // stops the event to bubbleup the dom
   alert('test')
```

if case is `2` then probably you want to use `.one()`

```
$('#externalContactsGrid').one('mouseup', '.k-grid-content, tr', function(e) {
```

---

*I also need the browsers context menu to not show when **e.which == 3**.*

For this:

```
if(e.which == 3){
   $(document).off('contextmenu');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to stop the event bubbling

```
   $('#externalContactsGrid').on('mouseup', '.k-grid-content, tr', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      alert('test');
   });
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks..some one put downvote for that ans .that only i deleted post .now i posted that ans